# Unable to add attributed string with font Avenir Next Condensed [Swift 3]

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

```
    let s = NSAttributedString(string: "Percentage", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name : "Avenir Next Condensed", size : 20), NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : NSUnderlineStyle.byWord])
    textView.attributedText = s
```

I get the following error for the above code:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue _isDefaultFace]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000046930'

If I change the NSFontAttributeName to UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20), I can see bold text. 
Also on adding NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, I don't see any text at all.
How can I fix this?

Comment: `let font = UIFont(name : "Avenir Next Condensed", size : 20)` returns nil? Try with `AvenirNextCondensed-Regular` instead for the name (you have to use the PostScript name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- You cannot pass Optional value to where non-Null `id` value is needed.

The `attributes:` parameter is internally converted to `NSDictionary`, where its values cannot be nil. But `UIFont.init(name:size:)` is a faileable initializer, so its return type is Optional. In Swift 3.0.0, Swift generates an instance of type `_SwiftValue` when converting it to non-Null `id`. And store it in the `attributes`. Which is completely useless in the Objective-C side. (This happens even if the actual value is not nil.)

(Swift 3.0.1 improved some parts of this situation.)

- You cannot pass Swift enums to where `id` value is needed.

`NSUnderlineStyle.byWord` is a Swift enum. In Swift 3,Swift generates an instance of type `_SwiftValue` when converting it to `id`.

(Swift 3.0.1 has not improved about this situation.)

To fix the two above things, you need to write something like this:

```
if let font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next Condensed", size: 20) {
    let s = NSAttributedString(string: "Percentage", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font, NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.byWord.rawValue])
    textView.attributedText = s
}
```